# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxws:inInterceptors'

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, pom.xml

I'm using Maven in Java EE Luna and trying to fix the error in my beans.xml before I do the Maven install to build and test the web service that I built. There is an error at my code which says "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jaxws:inInterceptors'". The exact line with the error is the following in my beans.xml file:

```
<jaxws:inInterceptors>
```

I tried googling online and the suggestion was to add the dependency related jawxs to my pom.xml file, but it didn't work so I'm wondering what is wrong with my xml code..

This is the code in my beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

        <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

        <!-- Spring's component scan for identifying beans to be managed by the container. -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="au.edu.unsw.soacourse.addressing"/>

        <jaxws:endpoint 
          id="GNAFAddressingService" 
          implementor="au.edu.unsw.soacourse.addressing.GNAFAddressingService" 
          address="/GNAFAddressingServiceImpl" />


          <jaxws:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="GNAFAddressingServiceSOAPInterceptor" />
          </jaxws:inInterceptors>


        <bean id="GNAFAddressingServiceSOAPInterceptor" class="au.edu.unsw.soacourse.addressing.GNAFAddressingServiceSOAPInterceptor" />  

</beans>
```

This is the code in my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>au.edu.unsw.soacourse</groupId>
    <artifactId>GNAFAddressingService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Simple CXF Java-first SOAP project using Spring configuration</name>
    <description>Simple CXF Java-first SOAP project using Spring configuration</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- comp9322: adding a Maven plug-in from Apache CXF 
        for code generation (cxf-codegen-plugin). This plug-in
        runs WSDL2Java which is the actual tool that generates
        code from WSDL. This plug-in will run as a new goal 
        'generate-sources', which means you can also execute it 
        using 'mvn generate-sources' in the command line, or from 
        Run As -> Maven -> mvn generate-sources.
        -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.4</version>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                  <configuration>
                      <sourceRoot>src/main/java-generated</sourceRoot>
                      <wsdlOptions>
                          <wsdlOption>
                              <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/GNAFAddressingService.wsdl</wsdl>
                          </wsdlOption>
                      </wsdlOptions>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                  </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- mvn clean install tomcat:run-war to deploy
                    Look for "Running war on http://xxx" and
                    "Setting the server's publish address to be /yyy"
                    in console output; WSDL browser address will be
                    concatenation of the two: http://xxx/yyy?wsdl
                    -->
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-tomcat</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run-war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <port>${test.server.port}</port>
                                <path>/webservice</path>
                                <fork>true</fork>
                                <useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>true</useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- comp9322: maven-compiler-plugin part 
                        referencing JDK 1.7 instead of default 1.6
                        -->
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]-[version]</projectNameTemplate>
                        <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is space and a new line after xsi:schemaLocation=". Try to remove it and bring the first value on the same line.

Change

```
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

To this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<jaxws:inInterceptors>` node must be inside to the `<jaxws:endpoint>` node.
Example:

```
<jaxws:endpoint 
          id="GNAFAddressingService" 
          implementor="au.edu.unsw.soacourse.addressing.GNAFAddressingService" 
          address="/GNAFAddressingServiceImpl">

          <jaxws:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="GNAFAddressingServiceSOAPInterceptor" />
          </jaxws:inInterceptors>

        <bean id="GNAFAddressingServiceSOAPInterceptor" class="au.edu.unsw.soacourse.addressing.GNAFAddressingServiceSOAPInterceptor" />  
<jaxws:endpoint>
```